# Problemas con mi logica MYSQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql

Tengo problemas con mi lógica de base de datos, el fin de esta consulta es tener las tarjetas que están disponibles para ser usadas, aquí esta el query, la verdad no encuentro cual es mi error y necesito ayuda:

```
SELECT 
TAR.IdTarjeta, EST.Descrip 
FROM TARJETA TAR LEFT JOIN 
( SELECT Descrip FROM ESTATUSTARJETA WHERE IdEstatusTarjeta=2 )
 EST ON TAR.IdEstatusTarjeta=EST.IdEstatusTarjeta;
```

Answer (score 2):

En la sub consulta te faltó obtener `IdEstatusTarjeta`, ya que lo estás utilizando en el `ON TAR.IdEstatusTarjeta=EST.IdEstatusTarjeta`

```
(SELECT Descrip, IdEstatusTarjeta FROM ESTATUSTARJETA WHERE IdEstatusTarjeta=2)
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias, tenias razon, estoy volviendo apenas a las BD y estoy un poco oxidado, de nuevo gracias

Answer (score 1):

1. No veo la necesidad de hacer un `join` con un select, si lo único que traes es un campo, podrías mejor hacer directamente el `join` con la tabla.

   ```
   SELECT   TAR.IdTarjeta
          , EST.Descrip 
     FROM TARJETA TAR 
          LEFT JOIN ESTATUSTARJETA EST ON TAR.IdEstatusTarjeta = EST.IdEstatusTarjeta and EST.idEstatusTarjeta = 2;
   ```
2. Si solo te interesa las tarjetas que tienen cierto `idEstatusTarjeta` y ese `idEstatusTarjeta`, tampoco veo la necesidad de hacer un `left join`, puedes directamente hacer un `inner join` y pasar esa condición al `where`.

   ```
   SELECT   TAR.IdTarjeta
          , EST.Descrip 
     FROM TARJETA TAR 
          INNER JOIN ESTATUSTARJETA EST ON TAR.IdEstatusTarjeta = EST.IdEstatusTarjeta 
    WHERE EST.idEstatusTarjeta = 2;
   ```
3. Finalmente, la condición, a mi juicio, debiera estar sobre la tabla `TARJETA` y no sobre `ESTATUSTARJETA`, pues lo que te interesa es filtrar las tarjetas disponibles, no los estatus. Esto es algo más de *semántica* que de sintaxis, pero es como yo lo haría para dejar clara mi intención (independientemente de si hago un `left` o un `inner join`

   ```
   SELECT   TAR.IdTarjeta
          , EST.Descrip 
     FROM TARJETA TAR 
          INNER JOIN ESTATUSTARJETA EST ON TAR.IdEstatusTarjeta = EST.IdEstatusTarjeta 
    WHERE TAR.idEstatusTarjeta = 2;
   ```

Comment: muchas gracias , vaya! al parecer mi logica si fallo un poco (mucho).

Comment: @Alan, creo que la _lógica_ es algo que se va refinando a medida que se adquiere conocimiento y experiencia. Por eso voy paso a paso, explicando los cambios, para que se comprenda por qué de cada uno.